# how to create a masking or clipping gradient effect for my background-image?

Tags: css, gradient, css-mask

what I am trying to do is, mask/clip a gradient on my background-image. Below image is the expected result

[image]

but the actual result is the image below. The gradient just cover my entire background image.

[image]

This is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/darkkyoun/bzyvpr4w/25/), and below is my css

```
.container{
  background-color:black;
  height:1200px;
}


.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
   background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(256, 0, 0, 0.52), rgba(0, 256, 0, 0.73)), url('https://i.ibb.co/BPjySrv/card.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
  /* background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/BPjySrv/card.png'); */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Appreciate any suggestion and help, is it even possible?? what I have found so far are only for img tag

Comment: Not your only problm, but part of it is that the linear-gradient is first in the background-image list and it's the first one that overwrites any others (it's the other way round in a sense from the normal element precedence)

Comment: so i should put the liner-garadient in card::after, then my .card just load the image ??